# python: remove single quotation mark from elements in list. AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, list

from this list

```
lst=['a,b,c','d,e']
```

I want to obtain the following one

```
lst=['a','b','c','d','e']
```

so I assumed that first of all the quotation marks from the first list should be removed,
but this line

```
[i for i in lst.split(' ' ' ')]
```

produces this error message:
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`

How should I change my code to get what I need ?

Comment: As the error says, `split` is not a method of `list`.  It's a method of the `str` (string) class.
For example: `'a,b,c'.split(',') = ['a', 'b', 'c']`.

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus questions that still don't have answers. Otherwise please let us know what issues you still face, if they are within the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

I know I already answered, I just noticed that since the elements are strings and have comma separations, you could use `str.join` on the list then just `str.split` the result to get the desired output:

```
','.join(lst).split(',')
```

---

```
>>> lst = ['a,b,c','d,e']
>>> ','.join(lst).split(',')
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Note this works in this case but only because of your particular values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a list comprehension, it'll look like this:

```
[y for x in lst for y in x.split(',')]
```

The error is because you're calling `split` on a `list`, but you need to call it on a `str`. The `for x in lst` gives you strings as `x`, which you then call `split(',')` on to get `y`, which is what goes into the final list.

This is equivalent to:

```
output = []
for x in lst:
    for y in x.split(','):
        output.append(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first iterate through each text in your `lst` list, split those texts on comma and then flatten the split text's characters into a list like this:

```py
lst=['a,b,c','d,e']

character_lst = [char for text in lst for char in lst.split(",")
# character_list will contain ['a','b','c','d','e']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain
list(chain(*(s.split(',') for s in lst)))
```

or as a (slower) full functional variant:

```
from itertools import chain
list(chain(*map(lambda x: x.split(','), lst)))
```

output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Comment: Why use lambda here just use a comprehension. It's the more correct way over lambda/map: `list(chain(*(s.split(',') for s in lst)))`

Comment: Sure, but when my brain is in functional coding mode, I tend to use functional syntax ;)

Comment: Completely understood, I only say that because the functional way in this case is not only technically slower but also harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

Without imports or nested loops:

```
lst = ['a,b,c','d,e']

output = []
for x in lst:
    output.extend(x.split(','))
```